# Writing js that will pass ESLint

Tags: javascript, eslint, bigcommerce

I'm working on a site that will be on BigCommerce, and the stencil bundle function uses ESLint to check the javascript... I haven't had to write for that before and have just copy/pasted things I find in stackoverflow... would someone **please**!!! help make this code all modern and lint-passing?

```
const delay = 100;
let throttled = false;

function resizeHeight() {
    const circleWidth = $('.home4a p').css('width');
    const circleWidth2 = $('.home4b p').css('width');

    $('.home4a p').css('height', circleWidth);
    $('.home4b p').css('height', circleWidth2);
}

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
if (!throttled) {
    resizeHeight();
    throttled = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
        throttled = false;
    }, delay);
}
});

resizeHeight();
```

ESLint doesn't like the 'window.addEventListener...' or the 2 occurrences function(). [it also says that it is missing a space between function and ()]

Comment: Please explain exactly what the errors are

Comment: SO isn't really a place to drop code and ask people to fix it. Also, ESLint is highly configurable, so whatever *my* ESLint setup is may not match what they're running. Why not just look at their linting errors and fix them? I mean, there's almost no code here. Just fix the lint errors.

Comment: The one error you've shown should be easy to solve, right? It says the code is  missing a space between `function` and `()`. So add a space between `function` and `()`. Just work through the rest. I suggest that if there is an error you don't understand, copy and paste it into your favorite search engine. The result is likely going to be already found here on Stack Overflow. Good Luck.

Comment: [`npx eslint --fix file.js`](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#--fix)

Comment: "Doesn't like" is non-actionable. There's likely a *reason* it "doesn't like" it, like, say, it's undefined, like https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef#disallow-undeclared-variables-no-undef. As it stands you're (a) asking the impossible (we don't know their ESLint config) and (b) asking for something we won't do anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you read the error messages from eslint.

I checked your code and seems like you need the function to be arrow functions. Also your indentation is wrong inside the `eventListener`.

```js
function resizeHeight() {
    const circleWidth = $('.home4a p').css('width');
    const circleWidth2 = $('.home4b p').css('width');

    $('.home4a p').css('height', circleWidth);
    $('.home4b p').css('height', circleWidth2);
}

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    if (!throttled) {
        resizeHeight();
        throttled = true;
        setTimeout(() => {
            throttled = false;
        }, delay);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for everyone's responses - sorry I wrote a poor description... Ignacio - thanks for bothering to show me how to turn "function()" into "() =>"!

Comment: Preferring arrow functions is not a default ESLint setting, and in this case, confers only a small readability benefit since binding is not necessary. It's not a *bad* thing, but it doesn't "need" arrow functions.

Comment: Although you are right, _prefer arrow functions_ is not part of the default config, it is part the current _eslint_ config in the project he's trying to modify therefore he _needs_ to change the functions to be arrow functions in order for that project to build. 


I wasn't arguing in favour or against the concept of arrow functions themselves.